# Curl into Vault server running in server mode fails when running via Vault Docker image

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I've been running the vault server mode with the official example provided in the Docker vault documentation. Though the server started successfully I cannot interact with the Vault server via its HTTP Rest API. Find my docker run command attached below.

```
docker run -e 'SKIP_SETCAP=1' -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}}, "listener": { "tcp": { "address": "0.0.0.0:8200", "tls_disable": 1 } }, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h", "disable_mlock": "true"}' vault server
```

When I try to curl into the vault server to validate the vault server initialization it throws a Connection refused error.

```
ravindu@ravindu-Aspire-F5-573G:~$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8201/v1/sys/init
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8201: Connection refused
```

Given below is the message displayed when docker vault docker container is up and running,

```
==> Vault server configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8200", cluster address: "0.0.0.0:8201", tls: "disabled")
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v0.8.3
             Version Sha: 6b29fb2b7f70ed538ee2b3c057335d706b6d4e36

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
```

Given below is my local.json within my vault container,

```
{"backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}}, "listener": { "tcp": { "address": "0.0.0.0:8200", "tls_disable": 1 } }, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h", "disable_mlock": "true"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you can't curl is because you haven't exposed the ports.
You need to add `-p 8200:8200` to your run command, and use the port `8200` to connect.

Comment: My bad missed that one